# Linking a dialog box with ListActivity

Tags: android, dialog, listactivity

I am trying to get well versed with `ListAvtivity`. I have written some code that renders a List and when you click an `Item` in the List, you are taken to an Activity that gives some arbitrary information.
I am trying to figure some way in which, if the user click on an `Item` in the list, he is shown a `Dialog Box` with some information instead of going to a whole new `Activity`.


Source :

```
package com.mavenmaverick.listviewtest;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

 public class ActivityExample extends ListActivity{

 static final String[] CHOICES = new String[]{

             "Mercury",
             "Venus",
             "Earth",
             "Mars",
             "Jupiter",
             "Saturn",
             "Uranus",
             "Neptune",
             "Pluto",

};

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {                    
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      setListAdapter((ListAdapter) new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, CHOICES));   
      getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
      getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
      getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
      {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            switch (arg2) {
            case 0:
                startActivity(new Intent(ActivityExample.this,TestActivity.class));
                break;  
            case 1:
                startActivity(new Intent(ActivityExample.this,TestActivity.class));
                break;  
            case 2:
                startActivity(new Intent(ActivityExample.this,TestActivity.class));
                break;  
            case 3:
                startActivity(new Intent(ActivityExample.this,TestActivity.class));
                break;
            case 4:
                startActivity(new Intent(ActivityExample.this,TestActivity.class));
                break;  
            case 5:
                startActivity(new Intent(ActivityExample.this,TestActivity.class));
                break;  
            case 6:
                startActivity(new Intent(ActivityExample.this,TestActivity.class));
                break;  
            case 7:
                startActivity(new Intent(ActivityExample.this,TestActivity.class));
                break;
            case 8:
                startActivity(new Intent(ActivityExample.this,TestActivity.class));
                break;  
            default:
                break;
            }

        }  

    });
 }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can directly fetch your content in the `onItemClick`. Use the `parent.getItemAtPosition()` to do this. Since you are filling in your `ListView` with string arrays, the `getItemAtPosition` will return a string.

Your code should look like this:

```
getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
  {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
                String content = (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                // do something with the dialog 
                showDialog(content);
            }

  }
```

You should google around ListView some more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use/create a dialog within your `onItemClick` and set the **title** to the name of the `planet` and you can even `set the view` of the **dialog** to the style you want.

**sample:**

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        switch (arg2) {
        case 0:
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
            dialog.setTitle(CHOICES[args]);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_to_dialog); //<-- if you want to add some view to your dialog
            dialog.show();
            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this dude it will help you......

```
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Youractivity.this);

            // Setting Dialog Title
            alertDialog.setTitle("AlertDialog");

      switch (arg2) {
            case 0:
                break;  
            case 1:

                break;  
            case 2:

                break;  
            case 3:

                break;
            case 4:

                break;  
            case 5:

                break;  
            case 6:

                break;  
            case 7:

                break;
            case 8:

                break;  
            default:
                break;
            }
 // Setting Dialog Message
            alertDialog.setMessage("A Planet in the Solar System"+arg2+"listview Item clicked");
            // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {

                // Write your code here to invoke YES event
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on YES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

      // Showing Alert Message
            alertDialog.show();  

            }
```

Comment: I figured out some other way :)